Uniform convergence of Doob's martingale
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a complete probabilty space, let $B$ be a Banach space and let $X \in L^1(\Omega, B)$. Consider a filtration $\mathcal{F} = (\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N})$ on said probability space. We define Doob's martingale via
\begin{align*}
M_n^A := E(1_A(X) \, \vert \, \mathcal{F}_n)
\end{align*}
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(B)$ (Borel $\sigma$-algebra).
It is known that, by Doob's martingale convergence theorem / Levy's upward theorem, $M_n$ converges to $M^A := E(1_A(X) \, \vert \, \mathcal{F}_\infty)$ almost surely and in $L^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$. Are there any results on when this convergence happens uniformly in $A$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\sup_{A \in \mathcal{B}(B)} \Vert M_n^A - M^A \Vert \rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
I have the feeling that there might be a counterexample at least in this general setup. Any help would be appreciated!
